# Python code for converting two mode matrix data into one-mode

Tags: python, social-networking

Being a novice on Python, I am wondering if there is any way possible I can convert two mode matrix data into one mode using Python code.

This is to create a data for social network analysis, and I am looking for a way to use Pandas and Python to create such a  script.

Provided I have two mode data llke this,

```
     workshop1     workshop2     workshop3    workshop4
```

A             1                0                    1                   1

B              0                1                    1                  0

C              1                 1                   1                  0

D               0                0                   0                   1

I need to convert that into one mode matrix like this.

```
           A        B        C          D
```

A          4         1          2          1

B           1         4         2           0

C           2         2         4           0

D           1         0         0            4

A,B,C,D are names of persons registered for workshops, "1" means the specific person signed up for the workshop.

One-mode matrix data indicate how many times they are supposed to meet each other at workshops. For example, A and C are expected to meet two times at workshop 1 and workshop3.

Thank you any advise or help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### NumPy solution:

According to [this tutorial](http://www.davidsherlock.info/network-analysis) you can simply multiply the matrix with it's transpose. Using the NumPy functions `dot()` and `transpose()` (or the short form `T`) you end up with the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

M = np.array([
    [1,0,1,1],
    [0,1,1,0],
    [1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1]])

print M.dot(M.T)
```

Output:

```
[[3 1 2 1]
 [1 2 2 0]
 [2 2 3 0]
 [1 0 0 1]]
```

Only the diagonals are not 4 as you requested.  In contrast they contain the number of workshops a person attended. You can easily fix that with `np.fill_diagonal(A, 4)` with `A` being the one-mode matrix.

### No-NumPy solution:

In case you don't want to use NumPy, you can adapt a [standard matrix multiplication](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/multiply-matrix) to the special case of "R = M*M^T":

```py
m = len(M)
n = len(M[0])
R = [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(m)]
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(m):
        for k in range(n):
            R[i][j] += M[i][k] * M[j][k]
```

Or the corresponding one-liner with 3 indices `i`, `j` and `k`:

```py
R = [[sum(M[i][k] * M[j][k] for k in range(len(M[0]))) for i in range(len(M))] for j in range(len(M))]
```

Or directly  iterating over rows of `M`:

```py
R = [[sum(a * b for a, b in zip(A, B)) for B in M] for A in M]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, and I think ths will work for me. Just out of curiosity, I was also wondering if there is any way I can get the job done without using Numpy, only using basic python statements.

Comment: @함형건: I edited my answer to suggest a "pure python" solution.

Comment: Thank you! I again really appreaciate your kind reply!